# Filtering the chart webpart based on dates in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

I am using chart webpart control in sharepoint site by connecting it to one of the lists in my site (X-Axis is Proposal Name and on Y-Axis it is proposal creeated date).

Everything has been working fine till now.But the requirement now is that the end user must be able to specify from date and to date and the chart should be displayed only for the values in the specified date range.

Iam not sure how to approach it.Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks in advance.